# How to list all the Directories or Files, from a root Directory, in Azure File Storage -and- using the .NET Storage SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to figure out how to

- list all the directories under a single directory

-or-

- list all the files in a single directory

using the [Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net).

The [MS docs do give us an API endpoint to hit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/azure/dn166980.aspx) ... but I'm hoping to use the .NET Storage SDK which handles a lot of the low level communications (authentication, etc) for me.

Can anyone show me what it takes to do this, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please take a [look at our File storage sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-file-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/FileStorage/GettingStarted.cs#L152) for some code that shows how to do this.

Snippet:

```
//***** Get list of all files/directories on the file share*****//

// List all files/directories under the root directory.
Console.WriteLine("Getting list of all files/directories under the root directory of the share.");

IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories();

// Print all files/directories listed above.
foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
{
    // listItem type will be CloudFile or CloudFileDirectory.
    Console.WriteLine("    - {0} (type: {1})", listItem.Uri, listItem.GetType());
}

Console.WriteLine("Getting list of all files/directories in the file directory on the share.");
```

Comment: ListFilesAndDirectories is removed?

Comment: I know it's accepted but doesn't really answer the question of "directories OR files", it lists directories AND files. This isn't pedantic, e.g. I'm looking for a way of listing just Files in a Directory. Why isn't there a ListFiles? Even IListFileItem doesn't tell you if it's a File or Directory. Further (perhaps more pedantic) is it asks from 'a' root folder whereas this just shows 'the' root folder. This might be a useful distinction when dealing with file storage.

Answer (score 1):

```
var directories = fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories().Where(x => x.GetType() == 
typeof(CloudFileDirectory)).Cast<CloudFileDirectory>();

var files = fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories().Where(x => x.GetType() == 
typeof(CloudFile)).Cast<CloudFile>().ToList();
```